# How do i write to a text file and read back from a text file from/to a Dictionary<string,List<string>>?

Tags: c#

To read i tried this code:

In the top of Form1 i did:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

In the constructor i did:

```
keywords = @"d:\Keywords.txt";
            if (File.Exists(keywords))
            {
                LoadKeys(LocalyKeyWords, keywords);
            }
```

The function LoadKeys:

```
private void LoadKeys(Dictionary<string,List<string>> disctionary, string FileName)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(keywords).Select(l => l.Split(','));
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            foreach(var splits in lines)
            {
                var key = splits.First();
                var value = splits.Skip(1).ToList();
                try {dict.Add(key, value);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {  } } 
        }
```

No exceptions but in the constructor after calling the function and all is done the LocalyKeyWords is empty.

---

This is how im writing to the file today the keys and values:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var w = new StreamWriter(keywords))
            {
                crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly();
                crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "," + string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

Maybe now you will be able to solve the loading the keys and values in the constructor and also to solve the problem how to write each time im doing a change of the keys or values in the button6 click event.

Comment: Do you need the mentioned format of the text in the file? Else you could use DataContractSerializer to serialize/deserialize the Dictionary. (While keeping the file in a human readable format)

Comment: Your `LoadKeys` function is not updating the passed in `Dictionary` (`disctionary`), but rather, a local variable `dict`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting duplicate keys in your file if that is the code used to generate it.  Do any of your keys contain a comma?  If so, that may be causing the duplicate-keys issue.  In that case, you will need to either escape out the commas in your keys, or use a new delimiter in your file.

Comment: Jon Senchyna the key are not containing commas the keys are: for example http://www.googl.com then , then the value google here is how the output in the text file is looke like: http://www.google.com,daniel
http://www.google.com,test
http://www.ynet.co.il,ynet     key,value(http://www.google.com is the key then , then the value wich is daniel )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string line = System.String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MyFile.txt")
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         string[] tokens = line.Split(',');    
         LocalKeyWords.Add(tokesn[0], tokens[1]);
    }
}
```

You should probably wrap that in a try catch as well.

Comment: evanmcdonnal tried your code and getting error on: LocalyKeyWords.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]); the error is: ErroArgument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> and : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>.Add(string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Your code does not get the full value for each key.  The values are actually `List<string>`s.  You want to set the value to a list containing every token after the first.

Comment: This is incorrect, the just uses the second argument as the value in the dictionary when the dictionary requires a list of the,.

Comment: @Daniel: you need to use tokens.Skip(1).ToList() instead of tokens[1].

Comment: Vlad tried to use with the Skip(1).ToList() and getting on this line the same error as above in the first code example here: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: @Daniel: than there is a problem in your file where you read the information from: there must be no duplicate keys, as you are dumping a dictionary!

Comment: @DanielLip Vlad suggestions will resolve your issues, I'm putting them in an edit. Admittedly, I didn't read the question closely enough to know the value was a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path/to/file").Select(l => l.Split(','));
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
foreach(var splits in lines) 
{
    var key = splits.First();
    var value = splits.Skip(1).ToList();
    try {dict.Add(key, value);}
    catch(Exception ex) { //TODO: handle }
}
return dict;
```

Comment: Dharun tried your code but when running the program im getting error on the line: var dict = lines.ToDictionary(g => g.First(), g => g.Skip(1).ToList()); say: Argument exception: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: You have a line with the same key.  I'm going to revert to my previous answer which you can try/catch

Comment: `catch (Exception)` is somehow, well, not recommended.

Comment: Dharun no errors now but the LocalyKeyWords is empty now. I will show you how im using it in the constructo i will update my question.

Comment: You need to set LocalyKeyWords = dict; at the end of the load method. Also you need to handle errors, dictionaries do not support multiple keys of the same value.

Comment: Or change dict to disctionary.  You have typos all over the place so it's hard for me to explain.

Comment: Missing closing bracket for the dictionary `var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();` should be `var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very large file, strongly suggest using [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) rather than `ReadAllLines`,  `ReadLines` is deferred execution and does not load all lines into memory, `ReadAllLines` is not optimized much when loading all lines into memory:

```
var result = File.ReadLines("text.txt")
                 .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.First(),
                               x => x.Skip(1).ToList());
```

In case you have the same key, `Dictionary` is not good option, instead you can use:

```
var result = File.ReadLines("text.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(x.First(), x.Skip(1).ToList()));
```

Comment: It's a shame that you split twice.

Comment: @Yorye: well, one just needs an intermediate Select. :)

Comment: I would suggest `.Select(l => l.Split(",').ToDictionary(parts => ...`.

Comment: @CuongLe performance depends on how large the values are and how many lines are in the file.  I imagine it becomes less trivial if the file contains a large number of keys and each one is mapped to a large list of values.

Comment: @downvoter: pls see edit, and remove your downvotes if needed

Comment: @Cuong: (not the downvoter) if there are duplicate keys, the input format is broken (we expect a dictionary dump anyway), so the procedure should report this as an error.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon an above suggestion, this will group together any duplicate keys and give you the unique values for each one.

```
           // Turn the file into an Enumerable of lines
var dict = File.ReadLines("path/to/file")
           // For each line, turn it into an array of comma-separated values
           .Select(line => line.Split(','))
           // Group the lines together by their first token (the key)
           // The values of the groupings will be the "tokenized" lines
           .GroupBy(line => line[0])
           // Create a dictionary from the collection of lines, 
           // using the Key from the grouping (the first token)
           .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                         // Set the values of each entry to the arrays
                         // of tokens found for each key (merging 
                         // them together if a key was found multiple times)
                         group => group.SelectMany(values => 
                                  // ...ignoring the first token and filtering
                                  // out duplicate values
                                  values.Skip(1).Distinct().ToList()));
return dict;
```

For example, a file containing the following text:

```
1,a,b,c
1,c,d,e
2,e,f,g
```

Would be converted into the following dictionary:

```
1 : {a,b,c,d,e}
2 : {e,f,g}
```

As pointed out by @Vlad, you shouldn't need to filter out any duplicates, as the file should be generated from a Dictionary, and should not contain duplicates.  **I would strongly recommend figuring out why your file has duplicates, and fixing that issue.**  You could then drastically simplify the function that loads your file into a dictionary, removing the grouping and the `Distinct` call, leaving you with the following:

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("path/to/file")
           // For each line, turn it into an array of comma-separated values
           .Select(line => line.Split(','))
           // Create a dictionary from the collection of lines, 
           // using the the first token as the key
           .ToDictionary(tokens => tokens[0],
                         // Set the value of each entry to the a
                         // list containing each token on that line
                         // (after the first, which is the key)
                         tokens => tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
return dict;
```

Comment: duplicate keys should be an error, the file must contain a dump of a dictionary.

Comment: and you actually don't need `Distinct`.

Comment: You're correct that the file *should* be a dump of a dictionary.  I made this suggestion because the OP was getting duplicate key errors when loading a file, which suggests that it there could be duplicates (manually-created file perhaps).  `Distinct` is being used here in case the file contains the same value multiple times for the same key, an example of which is shown in the example text file.

Comment: in the original version of the question, the OP showed the code which created the file by dumpling a `Dictionary<string, List<String>>`. This implies that (1) having duplicates is strongly a mistake, (2) each of the `List<string>` keys may already contain duplicates by itself, so `Distinct` still seems to be not correct to me.

Comment: I will update my question with how im writing creating the file today maybe it will help you all to understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for reading basically you do the opposite thing as for writing.

You open the file (`var w = new StreamReader(keywords)`), read it line by line (`while (w.Peek() >= 0) { var l = sr.ReadLine()); ...` (or even better `string l; while ((l = sr.ReadLine()) != null) { ...`), and parse each line.

For parsing a line, you can use `string.Split` to split it by comma, so your key is the 0th entry in the list of parts, and the rest is the value.

Edit: added alternate solution without `Peek`, thanks to @Jon.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) You don't need to call `w.Peek()`.  `ReadLine()` returns null when it gets to the end of a file, and an empty string for an actual blank line.  Using `Peek` *and* `ReadLine` causes your code to make more reads than it needs to, affecting performance in larger files.

Comment: @Jon: actually, `Peek` doesn't has a negligible overhead, the data is anyway buffered. And we anyway need that data for the upcoming `GetLine`. Usage of `Peek` comes from the [actual MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx).

Comment: Fair enough.  I typically see storing the result of `ReadLine()` in a string, then looping until the string becomes null, setting the value of the string to `ReadLine()` again at the end of each loop iteration.  I guess both ways work.  I think `Peek()` is still (at least slightly) less performant than just `ReadLine()`, since the "just `ReadLine()`" method is the same set of instructions, without a call to `Peek` and using a `!= null` check, rather than a `> -1` check.

Comment: @Jon: yes, your approach seems to be more elegant because of its purity -- no need for extra function.

Comment: If you're already storing the value of `ReadLine()` to a variable, then I'd use the null-check, but as we've seen, it's definitely not the only way to do things.

Comment: @Jon: yes, the LINQ-based solutions are my personal preference as well. However, presenting them to a beginner I see as bad from didactic point of view. (Again, that's why I tried not to present a ready-to-copy-and-paste code.)

Comment: @Vlad I'm guessing that this comment is in reply to my answer, not the above comment.  I agree with your point that putting a ready-to-copy-and-paste solution is probably not the best way to teach someone.  It can be quite challenging to find a happy medium between too abstract, and too concrete.  I've added some comments to at least explain what my code is doing.  Thanks for the good discussion.

Comment: @Jon: well, my comment was by no means directed against your answer, just my answer happens to be the least detailed one. Anyway, you've got my +1 for nice explanation in the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
var delimiter = new[] {','};

var splits = File.ReadLines("text.txt")
                 .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                 .Select(line => line.Split(delimiter));
                 // Add "StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries" if you want
                 // Add ".Where(split => split.Length > 1)" to exclude empty keys

var lookup = splits.ToLookup(split => split[0], split => split.Skip(1));
var dict = lookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.SelectMany(s => s).ToList());
```

**Less debug-friendly, but less lines:**

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("text.txt")
               .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
               .Select(line => line.Split(delimiter))
               .ToLookup(split => split[0], split => split.Skip(1))
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.SelectMany(s => s).ToList());
```

**Example input:**

> 1, a, b, c
>
> 2, a, b, c
>
> 1, a, e, d
>
> 3
>
> 2, a
>
> 4, a, b

**Output:**

> 1: {a, b, c, a, e, d}
>
> 2: {a, b, c, a}
>
> 3: {}
>
> 4: {a, b}